# how to properly read unformatted arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm new to fortran, and I'm lost.

I have a 2d array... which I can save

```
real, dimension(256, 256) :: arr
integer :: fid

open(newunit=fid, file='test.dat', form='unformatted')
write(fid) shape(arr)
write(fid) arr
close(fid)
```

It works perfectly fine ! When I hexdump the file, I get :

- a marker, two integers (ie. the array shape) and a closing marker,
- followed by a marker, 256x256 floats, and a final marker.

How the hell can I open it again ! Knowing that the size of the 2d array is unknown a priori, but knowing that the shape is provided in the beginning of the file.

```
integer :: fid, r, c

open(newunit=fid, file='test.dat', form='unformatted')
read(fid) r, c
```

But from here... How to parse at once the `r x c` floats and how to put them in a new array (correctly shaped) ?

Comment: Once you have the desired shape, allocate an array to that shape and then read to it.  There are many questions here relating to that (and not specific to unformatted reading).

Comment: indeed, but none of them seemed to be appropriate to me since all of them iterate over indices in a loop. But it may be due to a misconception I still have with this strange language... thank you anyway @francescalus :)

Comment: In your case it's simpler: `allocate(arr(r,c)); read(fid) arr`.  You just need to match the record format written out, which you know.

Comment: Perfect ! I also missed a `real, allocatable :: arr(:,:)`... this question was not really a duplicate... but I cannot post a full answer, all is in the comments ;)